# Delay before slide show animation start

Tags: android, slideshow

My slide show Activity is one of my list view rows , when click the slideshow row it must open slide images with animation but there is a delay of around 25 second till first image appear ,
i try to change the time here:

```
int delay = 1000;
```

but that not fix it ,

any help will be appreciated , thanks

```
public class SlideShow extends Activity {

public int currentimageindex=0;
Timer timer;
TimerTask task;
ImageView slidingimage;

private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
        R.drawable.day_one_1, R.drawable.day_one_2,R.drawable.day_one_3, 
        R.drawable.day_one_4, R.drawable.day_one_5,R.drawable.day_one_6,R.drawable.day_one_7,       
        R.drawable.day_one_8, R.drawable.day_one_9,R.drawable.day_one_10
        };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.slide); 
     if (customTitleSupported) { 
         getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title); 
         TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_tv1); 
         tv.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));
         tv.setText("slide show");  
         }       
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AnimateandSlideShow();              
        }
    };

    int delay = 1000; 

    int period = 5000; 

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }

    }, delay, period);                  
}        
private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    boolean animation_one = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_one", true);             
    boolean animation_two = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_two", false);
    boolean animation_three = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_three", false);    
    boolean animation_four = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_four", false);
    boolean animation_five = getPrefs.getBoolean("animation_five", false);                          

 if (animation_one == true) {   
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);  
    Animation rotateimage1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);            
      //
      AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false); 
      s.addAnimation(rotateimage);
      s.addAnimation(rotateimage1);
      slidingimage.startAnimation(s);

}else if(animation_two == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;        
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in); 
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if(animation_three == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;        
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move);        
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if(animation_four == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;        
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sequential);        
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);   

}else if (animation_five == true) {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);       
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);  


}else if(animation_one == false && animation_two == false && animation_three == false
        && animation_four == false && animation_five == false){

    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_slide);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);       
    currentimageindex++;
    Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);       
      slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);       
    }
 }   
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {

    if (name .equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
    try {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View view = li.createView(name, null, attrs);

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    view .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);

    ((TextView) view).setTextSize(30); 

    ((TextView) view).setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getBaseContext()));

    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED); 
    }
    });

    return view; 
    }
     catch (InflateException e) {}
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}                                    
    }
    return null; 
    }
    });          
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
                                       }    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.slide_pref:
              Intent i = new Intent("com.test.demo.SETTING");
              startActivity(i);
        break;
            }
    return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: so where is a problem? do you want 5 sec instead 25?

Comment: what if the delay is in the calling activity and not in this?

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib can you explain more with piece of code please , thanks

Comment: I am saying: What if the delay was in the activity that called this activity? Maybe in the onPause of the previous activity?

Comment: It seems like both the below answer are useful to solve your problem.. but still you haven't even made any comment on them, aren't they satisfying? what problem you are still facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this piece of code :

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 // Create runnable for posting
 final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        AnimateandSlideShow();              
    }
};

int delay = 1000; 

int period = 5000; 

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

public void run() {

     mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
}

}, delay, period);
```

}

Write instead this code :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();   
 runnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
        AnimateandSlideShow();    
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
}
```

This will lead to start image without delay ,

then you can control the appearance time and the time in between image as you want,

Hope help you .

Comment: `This will lead to start image without delay`. How? You have only brought down the waiting time by `0.5` seconds.

Comment: @ user2558882 i test that code it start image immediately without delay , also cancontrol time bet images , with androidqq6 code even if you reduce waiting time it will not affect but with use handler.postDelayed you will get fine result

Comment: @user2558882 androidqq6 said (there is a delay of around 25 second till first image appear) , now with my answer code , there will be no delay , thats it .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `postdelay`:

```
private int mSampleDurationTime = 5000; // 1 sec
private boolean continueToNext = true;

Handler mHandler = new Handler();

mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mSampleDurationTime);
```

where `mRunnable` is your task:

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

 //...
public void run() {

   // do something here

   if(continueToNext == true){
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mSampleDurationTime);
   }

 }
    ...
};
```